ReduxのHooksのテストでrenderHook自体が「Invalid hook call.」というエラーが出て原因がわかりません
この質問はteratailでもポストしています
https://teratail.com/questions/mfj85hj9a39su1
概要
クラスコンポーネントで使っていたReduxをhookで書き換えをしています。そこで次のように、Reduxのアクションをディスパッチしたかどうかをテストしたいと思っています（元々あったテストをhooksを使うように書き換えしています）
しかし以下のテストではエラーがでてしまいます。
もし何か解決方法がわかればご回答お願いします。
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import nock from 'nock';
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import testActionTypesEquality from '@/__test__/utils/test-action-types-equality';
import extractActionTypes from '@/__test__/utils/extract-action-types';
import { initialState as hoge } from '@/models/ducks/hoge/reducers';
import * as hogeActions from '@/models/ducks/hoge/actions';
import { act, renderHook } from '@testing-library/react-hooks';
import { useContainerHooks } from './container';

const mockStore = configureStore([thunk]);

describe('FormTest', () => {
  describe('hooks', () => {

    const changeFiledActionTypes = extractActionTypes([
      hogeActions.changeField(),
    ]);

    const store = mockStore({
        hoge: hoge,
      });

    it(`should call actions [${ changeFieldActionTypes }] on changeField`, async () => {
      const wrapper = ({ children }) => (
        <Provider store={store}>
          {children}
        </Provider>
      );
      const { result } = renderHook(
        () => useContainerHooks(), 
        { wrapper: wrapper }
      );

      act(() => {
        result.current.changeField();
      });

      await waitFor(() => {
        testActionTypesEquality(store, changeFieldActionTypes);
      });
    });
  });
});

問題
上記テストを実行するとエラーが出ます。renderHook自体でエラーがでており類例が見つからないので解決方法がわからないです。
問題の切り分けとしてrenderHook内で呼び出しているカスタムフックをconsole.logに置き換えても同様のエラーがでるのでrenderHookが上手く動作していないようです。
エラーメッセージ
    Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
    1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
    2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
    3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
    See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

      44 |         </Provider>
      45 |       );
    > 46 |       const { result } = renderHook(
         |                          ^
      47 |         () => useContainerHooks(), 
      48 |         { wrapper: wrapper }
      49 |       );


--------以下はconsole.logに置き換えてテストを実行し、エラーが出たもの---------------

    Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
    1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
    2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
    3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
    See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

      44 |         </Provider>
      45 |       );
    > 46 |       const { result } = renderHook(
         |                          ^
      47 |         () => console.log("a"), 
      48 |         { wrapper: wrapper }
      49 |       );

該当のソースコードはこちらです
import React from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

import { RootState } from '@/state';
import { hgoeOperations } from '@/models/ducks/hoge';

export const useContainerHooks = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const hoge = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.hoge);

  const changeField = async (key: string, value: number | string) => {
    await dispatch(hogeOperations.changeField(key, value));
  }

  return {
    hoge,
  }
}

関係ありそうなpackage.jsonの部分について
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-router": "^6.3.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "11.2.5",

試したこと・調べたこと
Reduxのhooksのテストの仕方はこことかを参考にしました

https://gist.github.com/Danetag/31982ad8d03afbc01042e3678445fd1c
https://medium.com/@skkashetwar/mastering-react-redux-hook-testing-your-path-to-robust-code-7c3f11acff0c

エラーの原因の切り分けをしたところ、renderHookのオプション引数（ここではwrapper）をつけた場合にエラーがでるようで、オプション引数をつけない場合はrenderHook自体がエラーになることはありませんでした。（ですがReduxのuseDispatchを使ったテストをするにはオプション引数が必要なので当然テストは落ちました）

他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿 をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？

なるほどです。教えて頂きありがとうございます。修正いたします。

自己解決しました。
以下のReactを使っていましたが、
"react": "^17.0.2",

storybookを入れておりその依存関係でreact v16も入っていて2つのバージョンが共存していてエラーになっていたようです。v16の方を消したら問題は解消しました。
